# Publishing WCF at IIS as https getting error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, config

We created a WCF service and able to consume locally.
When published it at IIS and consume it as https its giving below error

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [https].

**Config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />   </appSettings>   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF_Portal_Service.Portal">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WCF_Portal_Service.IPortal" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>   <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>   </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, this is because the service endpoint with Wshttpbinding requires an HTTP base address. By default, it doesn't support `Https`. We could publish the service endpoint over Https protocol, it requires that the `Wshttpbinding` enable transport security mode.
Please refer to the below configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"></endpoint>
        <!--Add an extra endpoint to exchange the service metadata-->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.